# How to reverse spinner left to right without reversing the selected item?

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-xml

Normal Spinner are like this :

[image]

when I tried to rotate it using  `android:rotationY="180"` the selected item is also rotated seems logical

[image]

now the problem is the selected item is rotated making the the selected item text has no sense

the required one is the same as the first picture but with rotated spinner

Spinner XML  :

```
<Spinner  
     android:id="@+id/privacySpinner"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/eventPrivacy"     
     android:layout_alignParentRight="@id/eventPrivacy"
     android:prompt="@string/event_privacy"
     android:entries="@array/privacy_levels"         
     android:rotationY="180"
/>
```

Comment: Keep the rotation on the Spinner, but also add rotation on the textview you are using to display the text?

Comment: @Blundell I don't use `TextView` the text appearing here is the selected item from spinner

Comment: Yes, but you can assign a View to the selected item, so do that and set it's rotation back the other way

Comment: @Blundell so how to assign view to selected item, if you can publish an answer it will be great :)

Comment: @Blundell thanks for your tip I solved the issue but you can post an accepted answer with +1 vote :) cuz that can help any one later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by selecting the 'item selected' since it's called back as view (textView) 
then rotating it back.The item selected is rotated back

```
  privacySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id) {

                  if(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar"))
                    view.setRotationY(180);// rotating the view (Selected Item) back 
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the rotation on the Spinner, but also add rotation on the textview you are using to display the text.

i.e. assign a View to the selected item, and set it's rotation back the other way.

pseudo:

```
spinner.setAdapter(...);
spinner.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_view);

myView .. setRotationY = 180
```

ref
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setDropDownViewResource(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setDropDownViewResource%28int%29)

Comment: `setDropDownViewResource` is deprecated can't find it in JellyBean Check what I did down

Comment: no it isn't deprecated. It is a method on `ArrayAdapter` I linked above